# Building reusable components with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm just starting out with MeteorJS and, coming from ReactJS and AngularJS, I'm finding a gaping hole where I feel reusable components should be. Meteor templates seem great for reusing and repeating swaths of code, but what about things like special buttons, date pickers, and the like? Should I be using these frameworks on top of meteor? How does that fit in with Blaze? On that subject, what does blaze even do exactly? Or am I limited to jquery plugins (aka bootstrap) initialized in the template.rendered function?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Meteor. For plugins like datepickers and , you can the package manager and find the packages at https://atmospherejs.com/

Comment: I think I'm on a good start, here.  Check out my [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/rxXfamARBBFt6wpFZ/Directives) on line 14 in main.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blaze forces you to use jQuery to do dynamic DOM manipulation. With ReactJS the DOM can be manipulated via it's state and props, much easier to debug and write. ReactJS avoids jQuery soup, it's easier to understand your code.

However I've spend hours trying to get a multiple file ReactJS app working in Meteor and still no luck. The `react-meteor` package only works with a single JSX file, and throws errors when building for Android using Meteor's included Android build tools. I submitted issues on https://github.com/reactjs/react-meteor/issues

I don't see why you cannot build a single button or date picker using Blaze partials. i.e.

`{{> custom-button }}`.

> On that subject, what does blaze even do exactly?

My dumb answer, Blaze makes it so your client/browser DOES NOT have to poll the server every X seconds to see if there's a change that should appear in the client/DOM.

My understanding with ReactJS and is you would still have to poll the server, unless of course you use ReactJS with Meteor. So if you had an Express server with ReactJS on the client you'd need to poll for changes, or use Socket.io, and for non-trivial apps use Flux. Meteor would simplify the glue/plubming... if I could only get it working !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Blaze Components](http://components.meteor.com/) package. (I am one of authors.) It provides an extension on top of Blaze which gives you reusable and extendable components.

I would also like to claim that @Giant-Elk answer is incorrect. Blaze does not force you to use jQuery to do dynamic manipulation. I would even claim that this is the same thing as with React. The point is that you should create your own reactive state you care about and then you use that in template helpers to decide what to show and leave to Blaze to then render and dynamically modify things. So the idea is that you have a reactive state which you define and modify, and you declare how that state should be rendered, and then Blaze takes care that it renders the DOM based on that state and updates DOM when state changes, automatically, reactively.

It has nothing with polling the server. Where reactivity comes depends on your code. It can come from the server side publish endpoint of documents, or from some other source of reactivity on the client. The main point is that the state (often the data context in Blaze) changes and Blaze updates DOM based on that. And yes, the state can be coming from the server and then you do have to care about how it is being updated and maintained from the server. But this is the nature of Meteor, not Blaze itself.